# How can I add a hyphen according the language on CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a question related the language and css. I'm working in a project and in the mobile version its necessary break a especific word.

The word is "Buchungssystem" (its a H1 tag) and in the mobile version its necessary broken to "Buchungs-
system"

How I do this?

Comment: are you using bootstrap?

Comment: That won't be possible like that. But you can use media queries to show or hide a specific class depending on the window with

Comment: No, I'm not using bootstrap.

Comment: There is the CSS `hyphens` property, which does what you want, but it doesn't work in all browsers. Otherwise, would it help to put a soft hyphen `&#173;` in the word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use javascript to check the width of the screen using `screen.width` and if the width is less than 1080px (assuming a full-hd display), the h1 tag should have "Buchungs- system" as the innerHTML text. I'll show you.

HTML:

```
<h1 id="heading"></h1>
```

Javascript:

```
if(screen.width < 1080) 
    document.getElementById("heading").innerHTML = "Buchungs-system";
else 
    document.getElementById("heading").innerHTML = "Buchungssystem";
```

Answer (score 6):

I would use a [soft hyphen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_hyphen) to inform the browser where it should break if the word is too long.

You would then get something like `Buchungs&shy;system`. If a word break is needed, the browser should then try to place that at (one of the) soft hyphen position(s) in the word.

Answer (score 1):

Could this help you with your problem ?

```css
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 80px;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid red;
    -moz-hyphens: manual;
    -ms-hyphens: manual;
    hyphens: manual;
}
```

```html
<div>Buchungs&shy;system&shy;</div>
```

The way it works is that you insert a ­ where you want to add a hyphen.As you make the width of the `div` smaller you can see that your word is splitted.

Next thing is to make page responsive to all device.

- 1. Set the viewport meta tag in head:
- 2. Use media queries.
- 3. Or we can directly use RWD framework:

     - Bootstrap
     - Foundation etc.

I added a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3gezf4fw/) so you can test it by yourself